# An elementary question on blocks and string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I have a doubt in one of the problems, I came across in a book.

[image]

Though I searched answers for it, I was not able to develop a satisfactory understanding.

The question asks us to draw a free body diagram of each block and find the acceleration of each block.

Most of the answers take the system to have a acceleration of $a$ and proceed.

Then, it is taken that each block has the same acceleration $a$.

This is the part which confused me the most.

How can each block have the same acceleration even if it is acted upon by different forces?

Can someone please help by providing an alternate solution or an appropriate explanation. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The acceleration are equl, because the constraints between the mass $~a_j-a_i=0~$

Comment: The assumptions here are that the string is inextensible (can't be stretched) so that the distance between the blocks is fixed, and that the blocks are perfectly rigid so that they do not deform.And finally, the strings are taken as massless.   With all of those idealizations (and probably one or two more) the velocity and accelerations of the blocks are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by contradiction, imagine that masses move with different acceleration. Then you can imagine that there is relative motion between the blocks i.e. if you sit on one block you can see one block coming towards you or going away.

But in these elementary cases wires are often inextensible, so if wires are completely taut, relative motion in one particular direction (relative motion is possible in circular motion case) isn't possible without breaking the wire.

That's why the only condition is that acceleration is same for all masses which is defined as 'constraint of the system'. Comment for more doubts, hope it helps.